# Variable assignment fails if called with sudo

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

I have to do an assignment like `m=7` from the C++ command line application. When I run this application using `sudo MyApp`, the command present in the program fails to execute.

```
sudo m=7
```

fails with the following error

***`Command Not Found`***.

Is there any way so that I can assign value to a variable with the `sudo` keyword present in the command?
Basically I want a way to do `sudo {Assignment}`  i.e. `sudo m=3`. Thanks.

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In my C++ program, I have to run some commands from the terminal. So assignment described above is one of them. However when I run that application using sudo MyApp, the sudo keyword is appended to all the commands that I run from within my program. That's when the assignment operation fails.

Comment: When you do `m=3` in the terminal, it assigns value 3 to m. Right!. Now when I do `sudo m=3`, it fails. So is there any way to achieve the assignment operation even when we are using sudo? Like--> `sudo {m=Some Code}` so that I get a value assigned to m.

Comment: Incorrect. It tells the *shell* to assign 3 to the variable `m`. `sudo` is not a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sudo` command allows one to run an **external command** as a given user (default: root). `m=7` is not an external command and hence cannot be run by sudo. It is a variable assignment statement that is directly interpreted and executed by the current shell.

The `Command not found` message indicates that sudo failed to find an executable command named m=7.

In fact, it is hard to imagine what the intended goal of running `sudo m=7` might be. If you want to assign 7 to the shell variable `m` you do not need any special privileges or `sudo` for that, just run `m=7`. If you want to open root shell and execute some commands there starting with `m=7` just start with `sudo bash` and then issue the `m=7` statement.